# Unable to traceroute from RSA Authentication Manager to Windows Host Machine

Tags: networking, vmware, connection, hosts, traceroute

I'm setting up my virtual environment for a virtual machine like this,
[image: architecture]

**Problem :** 
Here,  I need to test, whether my windows host browser and the RSA AM VM is able to connect or not.

**Try:** 
For this I have try traceroute command from the RSA AM virtual machine console. 
Then I got the result as like below

[image: trace route snapshot]

that is, i'm able to connect to the default gateway of RSA AM(192.168.216.2)  but I unable to connect to the windows host. why it is happening? why I'm not able to connect to windows host( ie. 10.100.7.148)

Note: All things are testing on Windows 10 Environment